# WordPress website's index.php show unusual code

Tags: wordpress

I was cleaning my hacked WordPress website and I found unusual code in index.php.

Is this the code used to hack my website? Or does it come from a plugin?

[image]

Comment: Seeing that the code is partially obfuscated I think it's pretty clear that it's malware. You should remove all that from your index.php file.

Comment: Looks very much like malware. Be aware that even when removed, there may be other files within your project which may add the code back into the index.php file. You should run a scan of your site and remove the offending files. Try WordFence freemium.

Answer (score 0):

Your site is hacked.
I would use wp migrate DB to make a copy of the database, reinstall a fresh version of wordpress and all your plugins.